# Loading server data from collection into views not work in backbone js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have used the following codes to load json data from collection into view. How i can load the json data from server into views through collection, i have tried as below

**Codes to load defined json data into views (It Works)**

```
// Person Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Guest User',
        age: 30,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});

// A List of People
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});


// View for all people
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(person) {
            var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

// The View for a Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',


    template: _.template($('#personTemplate').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});

var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection([
    {
        name: 'Mohit Jain',
        age: 26
    },
    {
        name: 'Taroon Tyagi',
        age: 25,
        occupation: 'web designer'
    },
    {
        name: 'Rahul Narang',
        age: 26,
        occupation: 'Java Developer'
    }
]);

var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: peopleCollection });
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

**Code to load server json data into views (Not Works)**

```
 // Person Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();

// A List of People
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url: "test.json"
});

var Peoples = new PeopleCollection();

// View for all people
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    collection: Peoples,
    render: function() {
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.collection.each(function(person) {
            var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

// The View for a Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',


    template: _.template($('#personTemplate').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});

var Peoples = new PeopleCollection();

var peopleView = new PeopleView();
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

**test.json**

```
[{name: 'Mohit Jain',age: 26},{name: 'Taroon Tyagi',age: 25,occupation: 'web designer'},{name: 'Rahul Narang',age: 26,occupation: 'Java Developer'}]
```

**html**

```
<script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
    <strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= age %>) - <%= occupation %>
</script>
```

Please guide me if i am not following any standards of backbone to render collection into views

Answer (score 2):

```
var Peoples = new PeopleCollection();

Peoples.fetch(); // <-- you're missing this

var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: Peoples });
```

You need to fetch the collection before you display it.

Also, you need to listen for changes on the collection and rerender the view:

```
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
     this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);
   },
   // same code as before
});
```

Finally, your render code shouldn't fetch the collection, but it should put the result in the DOM (so that what the user sees gets refreshed when the collection changes):

```
render: function(){
    // REMOVE THIS !
    //this.collection.fetch();
    this.collection.each(function(person) {
        var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
        this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
    }, this);

    $("#people-container").html(this.el);
}
```

Of course, for the code above to work, you'll need an element in the page with an id of "people-container", e.g.:

```
<div id="people-container"></div>
```

Comment: I have updated the codes, i have user this.collection.fetch() but still not works

Answer (score 0):

When you call `this.collection.fetch();` the way you do it, it loads the data from the server asynchronously, so when you render your view your data are not yet loaded.

Try to link the rendering of your view to the data loading like this :

```
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',
collection: Peoples,
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
},
render: function() {
    // this.collection.fetch(); => no needs for this
    this.collection.each(function(person) {
        var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
        this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
    }, this);

    return this;
}
});
```

Comment: listenTo not works, it says listenTo is not a function but i have used this.collection.on('reset', this.render); not works. Kindly suggest

Comment: when you say not works, did it gave you an error or what ? Have you tried `this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); ` added a new parameter `this` at the end.

Comment: Yes i tried but while printing at console it not prints "console.log(this.collection)" it shows entire backbone collections class variables and methods